# How should I split and retain elements using strsplit?

Tags: r, strsplit

What a strsplit function in R does is, match and delete a given regular expression to split the rest of the string into vectors.

```
>strsplit("abc123def", "[0-9]+")
[[1]]
[1] "abc" ""    ""    "def"
```

But how should I split the string the same way using regular expression, but also retain the matches? I need something like the following.

```
>FUNCTION("abc123def", "[0-9]+")
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "123" "def"
```

Using  strapply("abc123def", "[0-9]+|[a-z]+") works here, but what if the rest of the string other than the matches cannot be captured by a regular expression?

Comment: You can capture all characters using pattern "[0-9]+|[^0-9]+" or extend pattern to capture everything else and discard it from output using function FUN=function(x) if(grepl("^[0-9a-z]+$",x)) x

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer/135824#135824

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Fundamentally, it seems to me that what you want is not to split on `[0-9]+` but to split on the transition between `[0-9]+` and everything else.  In your string, that transition is not pre-existing.  To insert it, you could pre-process with `gsub` and back-referencing:

```
test <- "abc123def"
strsplit( gsub("([0-9]+)","~\\1~",test), "~" )

[[1]]
[1] "abc" "123" "def"
```

Comment: Never knew of the back referencing regex. This was what I wanted and thanks a lot.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman - Any suggestion for similar method for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571899/how-to-add-characters-around-elements) question.

Answer (score 10):

You could use lookaround assertions.

```
> test <- "abc123def"
> strsplit(test, "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)", perl=T)
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "123" "def"
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It works perfectly for this input.

Comment: +1: Not only does it work, I find this solution much more elegant! Consider a case where you would like to split formulas whenever you come across a plus or minus operator. In between you have variable names which you would like to edit. Therefore, you can split it up, remain the operators as separate strings, edit the variable names and thereafter recombine the whole set of strings again. Works perfectly with this solution without losing the plus and minus operators!

Answer (score 2):

You can use strapply from gsubfn package.

```
test <- "abc123def"
strapply(X=test,
         pattern="([^[:digit:]]*)(\\d+)(.+)",
         FUN=c,
         simplify=FALSE)

[[1]]
[1] "abc" "123" "def"
```