# How To Add Characters Around Elements

Tags: r

I am using `R` and want to covert following:

```
"A,B"
```

to

```
"A","B" OR 'A','B'
```

I tried `str_replace()`, but that's not working out.

Please suggest, thanks.

---

**Update**

I tried the suggested answer by [d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7128934/d-b). Though it works, but I didn't realize that I should have shared that, I am going to use above solution for `vector`. I need the values in `data` with `"A,B"` to split in order to use it as a `vector`.

Using `strsplit`

```
> data
[1] "A,B"
> test <- strsplit(x = data, split = ",")
> test
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"
```

above `test` won't be useful because I can't use it for following:

```
> output_1 <- c(test)
> outputFinalData <- outputFinal[outputFinal$Column %in% output_1,]
```

`outputFinalData` is empty with above process. But is not empty when I do:

```
> output_2 <- c("A", "B") 
> outputFinalData <- outputFinal[outputFinal$Column %in% output_2,]
```

Also, `output_1` and `output_2` are not same:

```
> output_1
[[1]]
[1] "Bin_14" "Bin_15"
> output_2
[1] "Bin_14" "Bin_15"
> output_1 == output_2
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: `strsplit(x = "A,B", split = ",")`

Comment: To clarify do you want `" 'A' , 'B' "` or `c("A", "B")`

Comment: .@lanWesley - I need this `c("A", "B")`. I realized why you asked this, after I tested the output of `strsplit(x = "A,B", split = ",")` coming without `,` in between `"A","B"`, as I am using this as a vector.

Comment: @d.b - Can your method be applied such that it doesn't split, but changes `"A,B"` to `"A","B"`? The `,` is important.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil, try `unlist(strsplit(x = "A,B", split = ","))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strsplit`:

```
> data = "A,B"
> strsplit(x=data,split=",")
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"
```

Note that it returns a list with a vector. The list is length one because you asked it to split one string. If you ask it to split two strings you get a list of length 2:

```
> data = c("A,B","Foo,bar")
> strsplit(x=data,split=",")
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "Foo" "bar"
```

So if you know you are only going to have one thing to split you can get a vector of the parts by taking the first element:

```
> data = "A,B"
> strsplit(x=data,split=",")[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"
```

However it might be more efficient to do a load of splits in one go and put the bits in a matrix. As long as you can be sure everything splits into the same number of parts, then something  like:

```
> data = c("A,B","Foo,bar","p1,p2")
> do.call(rbind,(strsplit(x=data,split=",")))
     [,1]  [,2] 
[1,] "A"   "B"  
[2,] "Foo" "bar"
[3,] "p1"  "p2" 
>
```

Gets you the two parts in columns of a matrix that you can then add to a data frame if that's what you need.